# Some Ruby code runs well in script/console but not with script/runner, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am actually using Rails 3.0, so it is `rails console` vs `rails runner try.rb`.  The following code runs well in the console but not as a script with runner.  I need runner (instead of using `ruby try.rb`) because there are some ActiveRecord code for the project.

**Update:** I couldn't run it inside of `myproj\lib\tasks\` (when the current directory is `myproj\lib\tasks\`), but can run it inside of `myproj`, so the question becomes, why must it be run at `myproj`?

```
http_header = {'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.53 Safari/534.3'}

url = URI.parse('http://www.google.com/')

response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.get(url.path, http_header)
end

puts response.body
```

The error code is:

```
c:\ror\proj\lib\tasks>rails runner try.rb
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:50:in `eval': no method name given (ArgumentError)
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:50:in `eval'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you running the command from?

You need to run the command from your rails root directory and give a full or relative path to the filename so `rails runner lib/try.rb`

The reason for this is that the command runner accepts either the name of a file containing ruby code or a string containing ruby code. When the command runner can not find the file named in argv(0) it tries to eval argv(0), so it is trying to eval the string try.rb

Comment: you mean runner actually tries to find the file `try.rb` starting from the root of the project?  Couldn't it actually just take it just like any other command like `more` (on unix) or `cat` (on pc)?

Comment: I believe that most of the rails commands assume they are running within RAILS_ROOT so they know where app/ lib/ etc are.